# Is there a faster way to capture a canvas pixel values than running getImageData?

Tags: html5-canvas

I am processing live webcam image frames to provide motion/telemetry data using javascript to control a web based game and to do so I use the canvas context to grab the byte data... context.getImageData(...

Are there other ways to read data from a canvas that I can try that may be more efficient?

Grabbing the frame from the webcam into the canvas takes less than 2% of my frame processing time (0.11ms), but running getImageData to put it into a readable state takes 76% of the time (3.67ms).

If I increase the image resolution I process the image by a pixel factor of 10 I only see an increase in processing of 15% (4.04ms).

Comment: There is a one time large performance cost for getImageData that is not directly related to the number of pixels you get. This is because to get the pixels means moving the canvas pixels stored in GPU RAM to the CPU RAM. which is slow to setup. On some devices getting a single pixel can half the frame rate. Consider doing the processing on the GPU using shaders and webGL. You will still need to move data back to the CPU but webGL can optimize this movement of data much better than the Canvas 2D API